# Duplicating items in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to clone items that have a char l in the string and remove items that have char r in the string, and do nothing when chars r and l exist in the same string, however, nothing seems to be happening when I implement the if statement I created for the clone, but works for everything else.

I created a for loop that will loop through each string in the arraylist list. It will first check if in that index there is both r and l in the string, and if there is it will continue, then it will check if there's an r in the string it'll delete it then return the list of strings, if not check if l and then add the same element in the last index of the list.

```
package com.codegym.task.task07.task0716;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/* 
R or L

*/

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("rose"); // 0
        list.add("love"); // 1
        list.add("lyre"); // 2
        list = fix(list);

        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> fix(ArrayList<String> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (list.get(i).contains("r") && list.get(i).contains("l"))
            {
                continue;
            } else if (list.get(i).contains("r"))
            {
                list.remove(i);
            } else if (list.get(i).contains("l"))
            {
                list.add(list.size()-1,list.get(i));
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in `main` and in your method program to the `List` interface (instead of the `ArrayList` concrete type). Also, you can use `Arrays.asList` to create your initial `list`. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("rose", "love", "lyre"));
    list = fix(list);

    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Then, in order to avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException` you need to use [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) (as the Javadoc notes *The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method*). And to append create a temporary list of items to append and then append after you traverse the `List`. And don't be afraid to store the `value` in a temporary variable (`list.get(index)` is both tedious and difficult to reason about). Finally, you can save the results of your "contains l" and "contains r" tests with variables as well. Something like,

```
public static List<String> fix(List<String> list) {
    Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
    List<String> appendList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String value = iter.next();
        boolean containsR = value.contains("r"), containsL = value.contains("l");
        if (containsR && containsL) {
            continue;
        } else if (containsR) {
            iter.remove();
        } else if (containsL) {
            appendList.add(value);
        }
    }
    list.addAll(appendList);
    return list;
}
```

which outputs

```
love
lyre
love
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with loops, iterators and `ConcurrentModificationException`s, try to do the steps one by one using streams.

First of all, get rid of strings that contain r, but not l. A simple `List#removeIf` method call is enough.

```
//Remove strings that contain r but not l
list.removeIf(s -> s.contains("r") && !s.contains("l"));
```

Now lets "clone" strings that contain l, but not r. In order to do that we will filter the list and collect the result into a new list of strings. Then call `List#addAll` in order to add them into the original list.

```
//Find all strings that contain l but not r
List<String> stringsThatContainLButNotR = list.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("l") && !s.contains("r"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
list.addAll(stringsThatContainLButNotR);
```

Comple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("rose"); // 0
    list.add("love"); // 1
    list.add("lyre"); // 2

    //Remove strings that contain r but not l
    list.removeIf(s -> s.contains("r") && !s.contains("l"));

    //Find all strings that contain l but not r
    List<String> stringsThatContainsLButNotR = list.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("l") && !s.contains("r"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.addAll(stringsThatContainsLButNotR);

    list.forEach(System.out::println);//prints "love","lyre","love"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify (add/remove) the list while iterating. This is applicable to other collection types as well.

Maintain two separate lists - one for elements to be added(`addList`) and another for the elements to be removed(`removeList`). Finally, from the main list remove the required elements (`removeList`) and also add the other required elements (`addList`). I have modified your code slightly as described above.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DuplicateItemInList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("rose"); // 0
        list.add("love"); // 1
        list.add("lyre"); // 2
        list = fix(list);

        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> fix(ArrayList<String> list) {
        List<String> addList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> removeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (list.get(i).contains("r") && list.get(i).contains("l"))
            {
                continue;
            } else if (list.get(i).contains("r"))
            {
                removeList.add(list.get(i));
            } else if (list.get(i).contains("l"))
            {
                addList.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        list.removeAll(removeList);
        list.addAll(addList);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
love
lyre
love
```